# Trying to use AngularJS with WordPress without any API

Tags: posts, loop, permalinks

I understand one can do this using the JSON RESTful API from WP but I don't want to go that route since it only works with sites on Wordpress.com and not on localhost (at least that's what I was told when I tried it and it didn't work).

Now, I am trying to pull posts into my `ng-view` using WordPress *loops*. The following snippet works well to populate my `ng-view` with the main blog page:

```
var asApp = angular.module('asApp', ['ngRoute']);
    asApp.config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/blog', {
                title: 'The thesite blog',
                templateUrl : '/a-s/blog/',
                controller  : 'blogController'
            })
    });
asApp.controller('blogController', function($scope, $routeParams){});
```

The HTML referencing the Blog link is:

```
<li ng-class="{ active: isActive('/blog')}"><a onClick="pagetop()" href="#blog">BLOG</a></li>
```

In order to ensure the main blog page contents are all dumped inside the `ng-view`, I have stripped off the header and footer codes from my active theme's **index.php**:

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

            <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
                <header>
                    <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
                </header>
            <?php endif; ?>

            <?php
            // Start the loop.
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // Previous/next page navigation.
            the_posts_pagination( array(
                'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
                'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __( 'Page', 'twentyfifteen' ) . ' </span>',
            ) );

        // If no content, include the "No posts found" template.
        else :
            get_template_part( 'content', 'none' );

        endif;
        ?>

        </main><!-- .site-main -->
</div><!-- .content-area -->
```

This works perfect. However, I don't know how to load the individual post page within the same `ng-view` when a post title is clicked on the main blog page (which simply shows a list of posts) displayed by the above snippet.

Can any WP ninja out there give me some ideas here?